# In Jquery how to refer javascript's element created by document.createElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code already written in javascript:

```
var objTo = document.getElementById('krishna')                
var href1 = document.createElement("div");
href1.setAttribute("style","float: left");
objTo.appendChild(href1);
```

Already so many elements are appended to href1 in javascript.

I want to  add some more elements to href1 using jquery

I tried `href1.append("<br>");`

it says `href1.append is not a function`

How to use jquery append to append an element to href1.

Comment: Any time if you need to convert native dom object to jquery object, wrap it with $. Like $(node);. If you  need to convert jquery object to native dom object access it by index. Ex $('#someId')[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the native element into a jQuery object. Native elements don't recognize jQuery methods

Try

```
$(href1).append("<br>");
```

If you want to do all this with jQuery alone the code is quite simple

```
// create new <div> element and apply style
var href1 = $("<div>").css('float','left');
// append to id=krishna
$('#krishna').append(href1);
```